# How to Find Total People By Their Total Weight?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

imagine you are on a room where 4people lived. let's consider there weight are below:

- P1 = 82kg
- P2 = 62kg
- P3 = 49kg
- P4 = 73kg

after sum we can see their total weight are 266kg (P1+P2+P3+P4 = 266kg)

now the question: is there any way to find how many people are there just by knowning their total weight? in this case its 266kg

Note: i know its a basic question but currenly i am learning math, thats why i put simple question here too so that i can get a clear overview

Comment: If you have a maximum and minimum weight for humans, you could get a range estimate for the number of people.  But you can't generally say exactly how many people given a total weight. For example, a total weight of $400$ kilograms could come from $4$ people at $100$ kg each; or from $5$ people at $80$ kg each.

Comment: what about you have 2people weight individually and total 4 people weight. (you have P1,P2 weight individually)

Comment: What do you think? You can try guessing a weight to see if it works. Then guess a different weight. Does it work too?

Comment: @paw88789, your answer is good. I guess to complement it maybe you want to add that the weights should all be an integer value. Not sure what other constraints are required to get a finite solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Suppose that instead of these $4$ people, you had $4$ different people, whose weights are $31$, $38$, $62$, and $69$

Now suppose I weighed some people, and I got a total of $100$.  Notice that this could have been from the $31$ and the $69$ persons, but also from the $38$ and $62$.

Or what if the total was $69$?  That could have been just the $69$ person by themselves, but it could also be the $31$ together with the $38$ person.

So, in this example, it is not always the case that given some total weight, you can tell which person(s) were being weighed.

Now, you have different numbers to work with, but maybe something like this could happen in your case as well?  I think that this is what your question is asking. So see if with your numbers you can get some different combinations of people that add up to the same total weight. And, if you think that in your case this is not possible, try and come up with an explanation (a proof!) that this is not possible ... in which case you *can* always tell which people were being weighed given the total weight.

Good luck!